# Newbie to GIS Development in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, visual-studio

I am new to GIS development and was wondering if there are tutorials available for development in ArcGIS 10. I have some experience writing simple scripts in python and fooling around in model builder, and I want to take the dive and make an effort to become a real programmer.  I need some more info to get a better grasp on doing some real GIS programming to make some custom tools in ArcGIS 10. Where/how did you guys learn all your GIS development skills? Any book/web site recommendations? Just an FYI I will being doing my coding in visual studio using the .net framework.

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/learning-net-for-arcgis-use-mainly-desktop-how-to-start